# Error while calling external AsyncTask from fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask

Can some one please help me with this issue . 
I am calling an AsyncTask when ever there is SharedPreference change in fragment.

public class UbiSavePreferenceTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    public final AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, Boolean> parallelExecute(JSONObject pref) {
    return parallelExecute(pref);
}
```

In My fragment

emailNotificationPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,Object newValue) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json.put("Email", newValue);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            UbiSavePreferenceTask savePref = new UbiSavePreferenceTask(mContext);
            savePref.parallelExecute(json);

            return true;

        }

});
```

but parallelExecute method in Async task in going to an infinite loop so i am getting stackOverflowError.
Is there any way i can come out of this error . 
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The method `parallelExecute` calls itself, so it is normal that it goes in an infinite loop!

```
public final AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, Boolean> parallelExecute(JSONObject pref) {
    return parallelExecute(pref); // <--- here the method calls itself!
}
```

I hope this helps!